# Generate service account credentials from gcloud utility

Tags: gcloud

I am looking for a way to generate the json that I would through the web ui from `gcloud` utility. From the documentation, I can see I can do this through an api request (https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts.keys/create). However I am trying to do it through the utility.

Thank you very much for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do this through this command, as shown in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/service-accounts/keys/create):

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create NAME_OF_THE_FILE.json --iam-account=EMAIL
```